# Ruby on Rails - Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

At the moment, after I post something in Rails, the time format is

```
<time><%= post.created_at.to_formatted_s(:day_month_year) %></time>
```

How can I get it to say **"about 6 minutes ago"**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<time><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago</time>
```